# How to deploy an Xcode app to iphone?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad

I know  a lot of solutions are out there. But here is my problem.

My company has already a developer's account and the device on which I want to test is already registered and it has a unique ID. When I open my Xcode and connect my device, it shows that device listed in the device panel with the given identifier in the organiser of windows. Now,  when I create a project in Xcode and instead of deploying it on simulator, I check the device button, it shows no device available. What am I doing wrong???

Comment: Did you check the use device for development box in the organizer?

Comment: i am using xcode 3.6.2 and it doesnot show any such option. One other thing, I saw it that when I click on the device panel it shows the following error.                                               The version of iOS on “device ” does not match any of the versions of iOS supported for development with this installation of the iOS SDK. Please restore the device to a version of the OS listed below, or update to the latest version of the iOS SDK; Can this be a possible reason for that???

Comment: Why Xcode 3.xxx??? It does not recognize your current iOS version on your device.

Comment: i am using mac 10.6.8 and after a lot of searching also I could not find xcode 4.2 So had to develop on the installed xcode 3.6.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

.                                                                    .

EDIT:

XCode 3.x.x is too old for development, why are you still using such an older version? App Store will not accept your build unless you use XCode 5.x with iOS SDK 7.x. 
Probably your iPhone has a new iOS version which is not supported by XCode 3. That's the reason why you can not see above option. You must update XCode to latest version and the Phone as well, then you will be able to debug in device.

Comment: ok..instead of this box, it is showing the following error.        The version of iOS on “devicename” does not match any of the versions of iOS supported for development with this installation of the iOS SDK. Please restore the device to a version of the OS listed below, or update to the latest version of the iOS SDK; which is available

Comment: the problem is that the mac on which I am working is version 10.6.8 which will at max support xcode 4. It doesnot support xcode 5.

Comment: Since february 2014, App Store will only accept apps which is built using XCode 5 and iOS 7 SDK. If you are planning to publish your app to app store , using xcode 4.2 will not meet the minimum requirement. You might want to consider updating Mac OS version , so you can install XCode 5.

Comment: actually I dont want to publish the app on the appstore. It will be only used for demo purpose by the people of my company. So I just want  to deploy it on the device. I hope updating the Sdk will do it..